# What is a virtual (derived) attribute in Java?

Tags: java

I'm supposed to make a derived attribute that will have accessors and mutators that deal with a value such as "Mark E. Brown."

I do not understand this term. It is new to me. Help?

```
    public String getFullName()
{
    return fullName = getFirstName() + " " + getMiddleInitial() + " " + getLastName();
}

   public void setFullName(String aFirstName, String aLastName, String aMiddleInitial)
   {
    firstName = aFirstName;
    lastName = aLastName;
    middleInitial = aMiddleInitial;
    fullName = aFirstName + " " + aMiddleInitial + " " + aLastName;
    }
```

Comment: Well, my understanding of a derived attribute is that you can derive it from another attribute.  Like if you have date of birth, you can derive age.  To me, accessor/mutator means getters and setters, if that helps any?

Answer (score 4):

Virtual or derived attributes are ones that do not have a corresponding single member variable storing its value but are instead derived from others.

For example a class that has first_name, middle_initial, and last_name, can provide a derived attribute called full_name with no back end string that stores the full name but instead returns the aggregation of all three of the the other attributes.

The trick here is that a setter for that derived attribute will have to know how to take the full name string and change the attributes it is derived from with new values.

Comment: So I guess my accessors and mutators would look something like in the edited code above?

Comment: that is one option and a good safe one. You could also make a setter that takes a single string argument and would split it up into the different parts, but that would be more complicated and less safe especially if you can have no middle initial or compound first names..

Answer (score 3):

Accessors and Mutators are basically getter and setter methods with the help of which we get and set values in a class rather than accessing those variables directly from outside to encapsulate your data.

Derived attribute is something that is not provided directly to you but you have to derive it from other attribute(s).

I can give you a hint that you might have to derive full name from first name, middle name and last name. So you will have to set and get these values and the derive a full name.

Please correct me in case I am heading in wrong direction.

Comment: So I guess my accessors and mutators would look like my code edited above?

Comment: See, in your setter if you are doing fullName = aFirstName + " " + aMiddleInitial + " " + aLastName; then you dont need to create a getFullName method as you have already changed the value of fullName using this.


        public String getFullName()
        {
             return fullName;
        }

This should work properly. Also, you can do setFirstName, setMiddleName, setLastName seperately and then getFullName can be used as you have written just now. I hope you get the gist