# What's the Difference Between C# and Java Class Properties?

Tags: java, c#

I was just trying to define a property getter on Java class and got told that Java doesn't use getters and setters, and does not, in fact, have "properties". ([What is a virtual (derived) attribute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945041/what-is-a-virtual-derived-attribute-in-java/19945158))

What is the difference between C# and Java "simple"/"value"/"property"/"attribute" class members and what are the advantages/disadvantages of each language's choice?

Take this Properties usage from C# below as example:

```
public class Dude{
    public string fName {get; set;} //this is what I mean by property
    public string lName {get; set;}
    public string fullName 
    {
        get {return this.fName + " " + this.lName;}
    }   
}
```

Comment: Although Java does not support properties on the language level, multiple libraries support properties as a very common convention.

Comment: Java uses JavaBeans pattern getter-setter methods to represent properties e.g. `String getFName` & `void setFName` with a backing private field (`fName`). As for attribute classes replacement, you can use interface annotations. The C# properties are simply syntactic sugar to simplify Java's way to denote accessor methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, you don't have a **syntatic** way to explicitly "declare a property", like you do in C#. It doesn't mean that properties do not exist in Java **semantically**.

From the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html):

> *To define a property in a bean class, supply **public getter and setter methods***.

So, taking your class as example, it would look like this in Java:

```
public class Dude{
    public String fName;
    public String lName;

    public String getFName() {
        return fName;        
    }

    public void setFName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getLName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setLName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return this.fName + " " + this.lName;
    }
}
```

If you introspect it with Java's reflection API and manipulate [PropertyDescriptors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html), you will notice that they delegate read/write operations to the getters and setters:

```
BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(MyBean.class);
PropertyDescriptor[] pds = info.getPropertyDescriptors();

pds[0].getReadMethod().invoke(..);  // Call to getFName()
pds[0].getWriteMethod().invoke(..); // Call to setFName()
```

Apart from the syntax sugar you get from C#, I believe the biggest issue with this approach on Java is having code error prone. It's pretty easy to copy/paste code and forget to actually change manipulated variables. With the C# sugar, as you just declare the property Type, Name and Acessors, you got less room for human error.

Comment: I've been working with an existing java app in my company and I must say this looks ugly compared to c#'s property.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado yeah, I kinda agree. There are some ways to get to a cleaner code with the same results though, like the awesome Lombok https://projectlombok.org

Comment: Also, Groovy, which takes a different approach to several Javaisms and interacts with plain Java easily.